# Limit of constant diagram on empty set

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

In the category of sets, Set. given any diagram $F:A\rightarrow Set$, constant at the empty set $\emptyset.$

It seems to me that limit  of $F$ is a one point set, the terminal object in $Set$? It satisfies the universal property unconditionally. Somewhat counter intuitive for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the empty set has a map to the empty set, so the one point set can't be the limit because you can't form a cone with it. The limit ends up being the empty set. Note that any cone on this diagram has maps to the empty set, so the vertex of the cone must be the empty set itself so the universal cone property is trivially satisfied.

Comment: It may be worth it to mention that any constant diagram wosd image is the object $X$ and the morphism $\mathrm{id}_X$ has limit $X$.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz That's only true if the diagram is connected. In general the limit is the power of $X$ by the set of connected components of the domain category of the diagram.

Comment: @ArnaudD. lf course, you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is empty, then you are looking at the limit of the empty diagram, which is a terminal set, i.e., a singleton. The required universal property in this case simply says that the singleton forms a (unique) cone to the empty diagram, and any other set does so, and factorises through the singleton. If $A$ is not empty, a limit will have to specify a cone to the diagram. But each node in the diagram is the empty set so the only candidate for the vertex of the cone is the empty set itself. The universal property is satisfied, quite trivially.